# Architecture with Neo4j and Mysql for social networking website

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, architecture, neo4j

We are designing the architecture of social networking website which has highly interconnected dataset. (like user can follow other users, places, interests. And recommendations based on that). The feed would come from directly following entities as well as from indirectly connected entities. (the places and interest can be connected to other places and interests in a inverted tree like hierarchy ).

Now we plan to use Neo4j for storing the complex relationships between entities with their IDs. We want to store the actual data for that entity in MySQL. We want to keep graph database content only to minimal size (but with the entire relationship (that's very important for feeds)), so that we could load entire graph in RAM at run time. (entire graph in memory for fast retrieval of content). Once we get ID's of object from Neo4j, we could run normal SQL queries on MySQL.

We are using PHP and MySQL combination. Now we have learned that Neo4j, if implemented in embedded mode, is suitable for complex algorithm and fast data retrieval. Now we need to integrate Neo4j with PHP. We plan to create RESTful Java APIs (or SOAP) for Neo4j implementation. By this way we could do it.

We would have atleast 1 million nodes and 10 millions relationship. Can Neo4j traverse 1 million nodes without perfomance glitches in 1-5 seconds with proper indexing?

Now, please guide me if this would work. Anyone who has already done this kind of things before. Your any little guidance in this regards would be highly useful to me.

thank you

P/s: i am attaching some project relationship diagrams to give you more understanding. please ask if you need more inputs from me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XA2uVZaFFTWDdwUEViZ2ZsbkE/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XA2uVZaFFTTGV4d1IySXlWRGs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

I published an unmanaged extension some time ago that represents a kind of activity stream. Feel free to have a look, you would consume it from PHP just via a simple http-REST call.

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream

A picture of the domain model is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, 10M relationships and 1M nodes should be no problem to even hold in memory. For fastest retrieval, I would build a server extension in Java and use the embedded API or even Cypher, and expose a custom REST endpoint that your PHP environment talks to, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html

Comment: Thanks peter. I guess i should go with developing custom JAVA API's. Have you ever done it before? and how was the experience integrating it with REST?

Comment: and what about time required for 1 Million node parsing? thabks

Comment: Experience is great using Java and yes, I have done it, since I wrote part of that code ;) Let us know if you have problems.